# Python 3.8 not importing Pillow 7.1 in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm in the process of learning Python, and up to this point, have not had issue importing that wasn't fixed relatively easily.

In following my course today, I was learning about Pillow, with 3 simple import lines at the top:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
```

Running the file in PyCharm returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"

In searching for a solution, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Pillow multiple times, as well as updated pip3.  My current versions are:

> Python: 3.8.2
>
> pip3: 20.0.2
>
> Pillow: 7.1.2

I was previously writing the file on my OneDrive, so my first thought was to recreate the file locally, and see if the location was the issue - it was not.

In another suggestion, I attempted to force install Pillow 6.1, but it ultimately returned a wall of red text resulting in an error that I have seen multiple times today:

> The headers or library files could not be fund for zlib,
>   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
> Please see the install instructions at:
>   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I followed the installation instructions there, multiple times, to the same result. (I only attempted after uninstalling Pillow)

I'm uncertain where to go from here, since I don't know what else could be causing the error.  I'm just following lessons, so the code involved is short, but it's possible I made an error setting up my environments... I just haven't had any issues up to now that wasn't solved by following the error resolution suggestions in PyCharm, which have not worked for this issue.

EDIT:
In trying to ensure that Pillow was imported into my env, I added import Pillow at the top.  PyCharm returned a recommendation to install it, which I attempted to proceed with.  It returned this error:

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/ef/e793f6ffe245c960c42492d0bb50f8d14e2ba223f1922a5c3c81569cec44/Pillow-7.1.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
    Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ozzie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v9m1qr47\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 860, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 914, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ozzie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v9m1qr47\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\ozzie\OneDrive\PyCharm\NewStuff\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ozzie\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\
```

Comment: is your pycharm using a virtual enviroment, are you sure you installing PIL into the env which pycharm is using to run your code?

Comment: I attempted to import Pillow independently at the top, and it predictably returned an error.  PyCharm recommended installing package Pillow, I attempted to do so, and it returned a lengthy error that I will put into my original post with this context.  One moment, and I'll edit above.